# in react native is there any way to transform long text to scroll horizntal like in books?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, mobile

i have a long text from a json file and i want to view it horizntal in pages like PageViewris there any way to do that?  here is my code :

```
    <ScrollView style={customStyles.container}>
      <View style={customStyles.verses}>
        {verses.map((verse: string, index: number) => (
          <Pressable
            style={({ pressed }) => [
              {
                backgroundColor: pressed ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)' : 'white',
              },
              customStyles.wrapperCustom,
            ]}
            onPress={async () => {
              sheetRef.current.open()
              const versesParse = verse.toString()
              // await AsyncStorage.setItem(verses, 'versesParse')
              // console.log('doneeeeeee');

            }

            }
            key={index}
          >
            <Text key={index} allowFontScaling={false} selectable={true} style={customStyles.verse}
            >
              <Text selectable={true} adjustsFontSizeToFit style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                {verse}
                {/* <Text>{index + 1}</Text> */}
                {/* <Image source={verseBullet} resizeMode="contain" style={customStyles.verseBullet}></Image> */}
              </Text>
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

[here is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivmnT.png)`